# How to get the error message from the require statement?

Tags: solidity, remix, etherscan, testing, error

I am using this test contract on Remix IDE

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.0;

contract testfunction{

    function test() public pure{

        require(false,"Testing require statement for Nordek Blockchain");

    }
}
```

When deployed on Sepolia Testnet, the complete error message goes like,

> call to testfunction.test errored: Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted: Testing require statement for Nordek Blockchain","id":7167807071665484}

But when deployed to Nordek Blockchain Testnet (RPC-URL- https://testnet-rpc.nordekscan.com/ , chainID= 58875, Currency- NRK, Block Explorer- https://testnet-explorer.nordekscan.com/, faucet- https://faucet.nordekscan.com/) , the error is

> call to testfunction.test errored: Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"VM execution error.","id":7167807071665554}

How to fix this issue and get the proper error message when the test function is called?
(Sepolia and other testnets run on go-ethereum nodes while Nordek uses openethereum, can this be a part of the issue?"

Comment: I believe that's just a limitation of Remix. Also, can y'all stop making blockchain just for the sake of making blockchains? We got more than enough of them already.